# Narrow range of pH for the formation of polyoxometalate clusters

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution

[image: Mo ions in different pH and cocentation]

The molybdate ion in aqueous solutions, speciates as clusters known as polyoxometalates (POMs) when it is acidified, but these clusters only aggregate in a very narrow pH range "polymeric range" in the diagram. What causes this pH dependence of cluster formation?

Comment: I hope I expressed better this time. Please answer or share any reference where i can find the answer. Thanks all